# Url parameters is not accessible in request object in Apiato framework

Tags: apiato

I use Apiato framework and I have a route that I pass a parameter in url like this:
/user/{user_id}
and I want to access and get this parameter in middleware but as I use methods like:

```
$request->user_id
$request->route('user_id')
$request->get('user_id')
Route::current()->parameter('user_id')
```

non of them give me that parameter and all of them return null while getting in these ways.
I'll be thankful if help me to be able get url parameter in middleware in Apiato framework